# Question about policy ID for native assets

Tags: native-assets, minting

If the policy ID for a some native token looks like this:

```
{

"keyHash": "wfwrfasdfasdfsadk4tjwljaldk1234567789123455678",

"type": "sig"

}
```

Can the token be minted and burned at any time by the owners of the keys? What are the limitations if any for a native token with a policy ID like this?

Thanks, Myles

Answer (score 2):

Yes - this is an example of an unlocked policy. Tokens can be minted and burned under this policy forever with no limits.

Here would be an example of a time-locked policy:

```
{
  "type": "all",
  "scripts":
  [
    {
      "type": "before",
      "slot": 28515365
    },
    {
      "type": "sig",
      "keyHash": "3a25088ecd68bde986becda8ebc51077222f981cab4214025ccc7bfa"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks so much!